# Why does C# IndexOf search for null characters return zero?

Tags: c#, null, character, .net-6.0, indexof

Here is my sample code using .NET Core 6:

```
using System;

namespace testTerminator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Given an array of bytes:
            byte[] array = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0, 32, 72, 101};
            // Converted to a string:
            string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array);
            
            // Why does the following line not return the position
            // of the null characters?
            int terminator = data.IndexOf("\0\0");  // returns 0

            // Output:
            Console.WriteLine("Data is '{0}'", data);
            Console.WriteLine("Found terminator at {0}", terminator);

            // Verify null characters are still in the data string:
            byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            for (int i = 0; i<dataBytes.Length; i++){
                Console.Write("{0},", dataBytes[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Data is 'Hello He'
Found terminator at 0
72,101,108,108,111,0,0,32,72,101,
```

Why does the IndexOf("\0\0") return a zero when the null characters are at position 6?

Comment: Seems like a bug. On dotnetfiddle, both the Roslyn and .NET 4.7.2 compiler produced expected result, but .NET 6 didn't.

Comment: @Sweeper - I'm beginning to think you are correct.  I've tried this on several online compilers and am getting mostly successful results.  Maybe this IS just a bug.

Comment: @Sweeper I cannot reproduce this (.Net 6 / C# 10). The code posted here returns the expected result. Where did you test it?

Comment: @Jimi https://dotnetfiddle.net/90K1Dp

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, but I don't mean some online service, I mean in a *real* VS Project.

Comment: See the [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#stringindexof) describing the change in .net 5 when they switched to using ICU.

Comment: @Sweeper Not a bug, as noted by AndrewS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461097/why-does-c-sharp-indexof-search-for-null-characters-return-zero/72463032#comment128008847_72461097) by @AndrewS in the comments, [this is documented by Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#stringindexof) The default is to use the `CurrentCulture`, and it returns `0` if there is an ignored character for that culture. In .Net 5 the Unicode library was changed, which affected this.

Note that you can reproduce this in a simple one-liner:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("abc\0".IndexOf("\0"));
```

To fix this, you need to use an ordinal comparison

```cs
int terminator = data.IndexOf("\0\0", StringComparison.Ordinal);  // returns 0
```

---

Oddly enough, when you use the `char` version it doesn't do this

```cs
Console.WriteLine("abc\0".IndexOf('\0'));
```

Returns `3`. This is because it does an ordinal comparison [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-char)).

Comment: Wow, I would never have imagined that `\0` has anything to do with culture.

Answer (score 0):

Since my rep is under 50 ı can not comment.
I tried your code on my vs 2019 community with Net Core 3.1
Output is as below;

"
Data is 'Hello He'
Found terminator at 5
72,101,108,108,111,0,0,32,72,101,
"

It is not a big deal but you may want to try with a different version of Net Core

Best,